# What is the (single) word for: the art/science of naming a complicated matter in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's kinda difficult to describe what I mean exactly, but I couldn't think of an example. Maybe I can add it later if I come up with one.

-edit-

The art/science of naming for example these complex situations within a single word:

• (not mine) "Waited a long time to read book. Read book. Didn't like book. Life now empty." "There should be a word for that."

• The empty but also content feeling you get after finishing a story or movie because you're "life" within the story stops. There could be a word for this.

Comment: The closest established term I'm familiar with is [*toponymy*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toponymy). It is a scholastic discipline dedicated to the study of place names.

Comment: You mean like EXTINCTIONSPECTROPHOTOPOLERISCOPEOCCULOGRAVOGYROKYNETOMETER?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a technical term, however if you're looking for a descriptive word for the action you might describe it as 'encapsulation'

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a technical term for the practice of consolidating to a single word, this isn't it, however if you're looking to describe what you're doing, you might say it is:

> [**Encapsulation** at Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/encapsulation)
>
> 2The succinct expression or depiction of the essential features of something.
>
> ‘his encapsulation of the concept’

Perhaps, you could coin a term "**Encapsulative naming**"